# Como adicionar um evento onBlur sem sobrescrever o original?

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho um código que é basicamente assim:

```
<input type="text" value="" onfocus="myFunction(this);" onblur="alert('1');">

<script>
  function myFunction(obj) {
    obj.onblur = function() {
      alert("2");
    };
  }
</script>
```

Como eu posso fazer para executar o evento onBlur original após o evento adicionado pela minha função?

Esse aqui é o link para a minha função completa, para vocês entenderem melhor o meu problema: http://jsbin.com/zedot/2/watch?html,js,output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Solução #1 (recomendada): `addEventListener`

Com [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) você pode associar tantos *event handlers* a um elemento quantos forem necessários:

```
obj.addEventListener('blur', function() {
    alert("2");
}, false);
```

Para compatibilidade com o IE8, você precisa usar `attachEvent`:

```
if(obj.attachEvent) {
    elem.attachEvent('onblur', function(){
        alert("2");
    });
} else {
    obj.addEventListener('blur', function() {
        alert("2");
    }, false);
}
```

Naturalmente é recomendável criar uma função para isso, em vez de usar inline como no exemplo acima. Um exemplo de função está na [resposta do Tuyoshi Vinicius](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/9317/74).

### Solução #2: guarde o handler anterior

Você pode guardar o handler anterior numa variável, atribuir um novo handler, e chamar o antigo de lá:

```
var onBlurOriginal = obj.onblur;
obj.onblur = function() {
    alert("2");
    onBlurOriginal.call(this);
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar a biblioteca [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) que já tem esse tipo de implementação cross-browser caso você não use, o código abaixo pode ser útil.

```
function listen(evnt, elem, func) {
    if (elem.addEventListener)  // W3C DOM
        elem.addEventListener(evnt,func,false);
    else if (elem.attachEvent) { // IE DOM
         var r = elem.attachEvent("on"+evnt, func);
    return r;
    }
    else window.alert('error');
}

listen("blur",document.getElementById('teste'),function(){
//sua função
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Esse é um problema antigo do javascript nos browseres, contornável facilmente pelo uso de bibliotecas, como o [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Usando jQuery seu exemplo ficaria assim:

```
<input id="txt" type="text" value="" />
<script>
function myFunction(obj) {
    $(obj).on("blur", function() {
        alert("2");
    });
}

$(function(){
    $("#txt")
    .on("focus", function () {
        myFunction(this);
    })
    .on("blur", function () {
        alert('1');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Claro que o jQuery tem muitas utilidades, mas incluí-lo *somente* para resolver esse problema seria exagero.

Comment: Só veja o problema de usar jQuery se estiver desenvolvendo a sua própria biblioteca javascript.